# Is this correct? "I can't sing very much myself."

Tags: grammar

I'm a student learning English as a second language.
I wanted to say that I can't sing very well, and I wanted to emphasize this sentence.
So.. Is it OK to say that "I can't sing very much myself"?

Comment: What's wrong with "I can't sing very well myself"? _Much_ is OK, but could be taken to mean that you can't go on singing for a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add "myself" in a redundant way to add emphasis.  There are other ways of adding emphasis.  "Myself" emphasises "me and not someone else"  But if you want emphasise "much" or "sing" you would need something different.

You should be careful not to change "well" to "much".  These have different meanings.  "I can't sing very well" means "I can only sing poorly".  But "I can't sing very much" means "I can only sing rarely"

> I trained at the cathedral and I have very good voice.  But I am so busy with work that I can't sing very much, myself.

> I was never taught to sing at school. Now I am a teacher, I sing in the school chapel every day, but I can't sing very well, myself.

In both cases the "myself" is rather distracting, and I would remove it.

Comment: Wow thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The “myself” at the end would be used if someone else had said they can’t sing first. Joe: “I really can’t sing.”  Jack: “Don’t worry, I can’t sing myself”

In your situation I’d put the “myself” closer to the start. “I hired a choir of ten singers. I myself can’t sing at all.”

“I can’t sing very much” doesn’t make sense. You could say “I can’t sing very well”. Or “I have problems with my voice. I can’t sing for very long / for a long time”.

Comment: Thanks! I was talking about my favorite singers, and I wanted to contrast them with myself.

Answer (score 0):

**to not be able to do something very much can have two meaning**s:

- I can't sing very much. = I am not a good singer
  OR
- I can't sing very  much. = I cannot sing for too long at one time.

The myself is just for contrast with some other person in a discussion.

Another example of the same usage:

- I can't swim very much. [not a good swimmer]
- I can't swim very much. [for too long a time]

Emphasis: I, myself, cannot sing very well.

to sing well is the usual expression but as explained above, it can also be not x very much.